# GTK - Set widget's window fullscreen

Tags: c, gtk

I have been trying to set a widget's window to fullscreen.

I tried getting the root window of the widget using `gtk_widget_get_root(_window)` and then using `gtk_window_fullscreen()` to set it to fullscreen, but the documentation says that `gtk_widget_get_root_window()` and `gtk_widget_get_parent_window()` (which I tried too) return a GdkWindow *, not a GtkWindow * as needed.

I tried casting GdkWindow* to GtkWindow* but it gives me this error:

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_window_fullscreen: assertion `GTK_IS_WINDOW
>   (window)' failed

The code would look like this:

```
gtk_window_fullscreen (GTK_WINDOW(gtk_widget_get_root_window (widget)));
```

I've also noticed that a widget has a field "window" but it is also GdkWindow * type.

I don't have the window widget in the function where I want to set it fullscreen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GtkWindow` and `GdkWindow` are totally different things.

When we think about "window", we usually mean a graphical component - the toplevel, resizable "box" with minimize/maximize buttons etc. This is what is represented by `GtkWindow`.

GDK however has another meaning for "window". The `GdkWindow` is not a graphical component, but an abstract resource inside GDK representing some rectangular region on the screen. It is probably closely related to some low-level resource inside Xorg/Win32 etc.

If you want to obtain the toplevel `GtkWindow` containing a given widget, you could probably use [gtk_widget_get_toplevel](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-toplevel) or [gtk_widget_get_ancestor](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-ancestor)